# IBM ODM cannot generate a valid WADL

Tags: ibm-odm

I've been plagued for months with an error in ODM.
It doesn't prevent my services from working, it only prevents ODM from automatically generating the JSON input payload when I test a service through the Rule Execution Server (the Retrieve HTDS Description File).

I attached a screenshot of the error.

What is puzzling is that:

- if I move my variable from Input to Output, then the JSON gets generated in the Server Response section
- if I manually enter my own JSON, the service executes correctly and I get back a decision

Does anyone have any idea what could possibly be wrong here?

[image]

Comment: What version of ODM are you using?

Comment: What is the data type of the variable you are having troubles with?

Answer (score 1):

hard to help as some of the context is missing. However the symptoms you describe tells there is a serialization issue one of the class of the HTDS interface.

It could be :

- a getter/setter missing
- a dependency missing in the XOM (classloader)
- or a **@jsonIgnore** missing on a non getter/setter method whose name starts by **get** or **set**.

Best
Emmanuel

Answer (score 1):

Very likely your variable is not being deserialized properly. This would explain both the error you are getting and why you get it only as an input variable.

We get a similar error using a java.tim.ZonedDateTime with ODM 8.9.1, which does not support the java.time package. We just ignore the error -- and are hoping we can avoid it when we move to ODM 8.10.2.